# How to change a WinRT ToggleSwitch color?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, toggleswitch

I'm writing a Windows 8 WinRT app in C#, and would like to dynamically change the color of my `ToggleSwitch`. I'll be having multiple instances of these, and they won't all have the same color.

I tried to create a custom control that inherits from `ToggleSwitch`, but I quickly learned that I can't do this because `ToggleSwitch` is a `sealed` class. My goal was to add a `DependencyProperty` of type `Brush`, and then consume that brush through a `TemplateBinding` in my custom control's `Template`.

Is there another way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for what it is worth I was looking for the same thing recently and found this MS link.  Just changing the colors to what you need no styling is necessary unless you really must go that low.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709931.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to do it in Blend

> Right Click on the ToggleSwitch > Edit Template > Edit Copy

Blend will insert lot of XAML in the `<Page.Resource>`. Changing the `Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain` property will change the color of the Curtain.

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchCurtain">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
```

Comment: That changes the color of the on/off content. The color of the switch is still a shade of purple (the default color)

Comment: yeah, I just tested that. Actually there is no simple way to change color. You may want to do it in Blend by creating a Style.

Comment: My question states that I want to be able to do this dynamically (being able to assign a value to/change a value of a property at runtime). Changing it in blend = changing it statically.

Comment: @KshitijMehta you can generate styles in runtime and assign them to toggle switch. By using Blend you'll get an idea what to generate though. I am not sure if that's most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="154"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchHeaderDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnob">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition" From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition" From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.CurtainOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchCurtain"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-44" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CurtainTranslateTransform"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="38" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Semilight" Margin="6"/>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="6,5,0,16" MinWidth="65" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="6,5,0,16" MinWidth="65" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Height="16" Margin="13,5,13,16" Background="#FF164151">
                                        <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchOuterBorderBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FF20C0FB">
                                            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchTrackBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF0ABCFF">
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainBounds" Foreground="#FFFF0505">
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="SwitchCurtainClip" Foreground="#FFFF0505">
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchCurtain" Fill="#66EC0909" Width="44">
                                                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="CurtainTranslateTransform" X="-44"/>
                                                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                        </Rectangle>
                                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                                </ContentPresenter>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnob" Fill="#FFFF1515" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThumbBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="0" Width="12">
                                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        </Rectangle>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Fill="#FF269ECD"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" Margin="-3" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1" Fill="#FF0A739B"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Thumb x:Name="SwitchThumb" Foreground="White" Background="{StaticResource TextLightGrey}">
                                        <Thumb.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Thumb.Template>
                                    </Thumb>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ToggleSwitchFillOn" Color="Red"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Add the code above to your App.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that is it not working

```
toggleSwitch.toggle.SwitchForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
```

reading more about your question you can totally switch the stly but you have to create sveral styles for togle and apply the one you want

```
toggleSwitch.Style = this.FindResource("toggleSwitchsTYLE") as Style;
```

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-toggleswitch-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api

Comment: This is for WP7, my question is about WinRT on Win8. The SwitchForeground property doesn't exist in the WinRT XAML ToggleSwitch. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.toggleswitch.aspx

Comment: Being able to create multiple styles is not an option, it needs to be more dynamic. I can't create **n** different styles for **n** colors; it's not a very maintainable solution.

Comment: THEN YOU GOT TO CREATE THE STYLE DYNAMICALLY

Answer (score 0):

I decided to re-purpose the Background property in a custom Style, where the value assigned to the Background property would be template-bound to the SwitchCurtain's Fill. Since I'd never use the actual purpose of the Background property anyway, this seems like the ideal approach.