# ToggleSwitch colors and styles

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Here is how the default ToggleSwitch looks like:

Enabled:

[image: off]

Disabled:

[image: on]

However, I want to put this widget on a page with a white background, and I cant quite get it too look how I want it to. I don't know how to change any part that is white in these pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the page-background, you can set the same property to layout grid.

If you want to change the theme (i.e. for entire application) use ThemeManager, you can find my another answer here: [How do I override the default Windows Phone theme for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263376/how-do-i-override-the-default-windows-phone-theme-for-my-app/18264031#18264031)

If you want to change it just for ToggleSwitch, you can do that in XAML by code or by using tools like Blend. I will recommend using Blend as it makes it easy. There are basically two states above, which you want to change. In Blend, you can right click this control and select edit-template and further change the states. You can find more information about styling controls in blend here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

There is also another similar question and it is mentioned here: 
[How to change a WinRT ToggleSwitch color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433882/how-to-change-a-winrt-toggleswitch-color)

Hope, this solves your question.

Comment: Using Blend since now on. Thanks.